# SQL Query, How to find the first and last value in the given table need by sequential order with conditions

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have ids in my table, ids start from 1 to 20, I want a query, to find the first and last records in a given table but I want the result by some condition.

For example: if I have the record

```
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13, 19,20
```

I need a result like  1-5, 9-13, 19-20  like this I need results

Comment: Is it sqlite or MySQL? And what version of it?

Comment: SQLite, if i get the query in MySQL also no problem

Comment: This is a 'gaps and islands' problem

Comment: @Strawberry what?

Comment: @angel.bonev if i run that query am getting the answer last min and max value but i need a result like above i mention, its not duplicate question

Comment: @Prabhu . . . Is that a comma-delimited value in one record?  Or is it multiple rows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **island** part of the classic *gaps and islands* problem (With the **gaps** part being finding the missing values in between each island). If you search for that term, you'll find a ton of material about how to calculate them.

One approach (Requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer for window function support):

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE ex(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
sqlite> INSERT INTO ex VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(19),(20);
sqlite> WITH cte AS (SELECT id, id - row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS grp FROM ex)
   ...> SELECT min(id) AS rangestart, max(id) AS rangeend FROM cte GROUP BY grp;
rangestart  rangeend  
----------  ----------
1           5         
9           13        
19          20
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL Query to find first record in your table:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY <column_name> ASC LIMIT 1
```

SQL Query to find last record in your table:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY <column_name> DESC LIMIT 1
```

> For example: if I have the record 1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13, 19,20
>
> I need a result like 1-5, 9-13, 19-20 like this I need results

If you need result like you have mentioned, then you can set `LIMIT` in your query to get how many records you can have in that query.

QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> LIMIT <any_number>
```

Comment: Limit, if i run the query first i will get 1, and last 20, but i need the result like above i mention i don need 1,20 as result